# Printing an illustrator template as a brochure

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I have an illustrator template brochure with pages inside one view, Can i print this as brochure
without putting each page on an individual view?

here's what I have
https://prnt.sc/sd5gka
[image]

Comment: Does each page have its' own artboard? That's really all you need.

Comment: @Scott Yes each page is in a layered group, when I go to local printing agency, should I give this illustrator as is? or should I alter it? I want the result as a brochure book

Comment: That's kind of a confusing response.... "Yes" but a "layered group" is not an *artboard*. So, I'm still unclear if each "page" has its' own artboard.

Answer (score 0):

No. You will get a poster exactly as you are seeing it, not a brochure.

1. Take the measures of the cover.
2. Make a new document with those sizes.
3. Copy each page and paste it on the center of that new document.
4. Add artboards and paste each new page on a new artboard.

---

You could still have some issues because probably the document has no bleed, so keep that in mind.

Comment: would you mean something like this https://prnt.sc/sdatmz ? I added whitespace considering bleed

Comment: No. White space is not bleed. Bleed is the inside color extended to the outside.

Comment: That is very sloppy work. Sorry, but you will lose money if you print that. It is better that you pay a designer.

Comment: @Sup3r - a page with bleeds looks like this [example](https://imgur.com/bBdebKi). The bleed areas need to extend over the page edge, and crop marks show how to trim the bleed.